# How to add another description block outside the tabs in product detail page

Tags: blocks, product-attribute, magento2.2.4, blog, category-description

I am using **Magento 2.2.4**. I need to add a block for product detail outside from the main **'Details', 'Review'** tabs. I need this block to be separated after the main description of the product. I have started doing this with a custom theme but no idea how to do this. I need to add something like a blog post end of the description of the product with images. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In your custom module you can add catalog_product_view.xml

> app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="[Vendor]/[Module]\Block\Product\View\Faq" name="product.info.faq" template="Vendor_Module::product/faq.phtml" after="product.info.details">
                <arguments><argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">FAQ</argument></arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Than write your custom template.

> app/code[Vendor]/[Module]/view/frontend/templates/product/faq.phtml

```
<?php
echo $block->getProduct();
?>
```

I hope this answer helps you. If you found it useful please accept it.

Comment: I have added a custom theme extended from luma. But I have no idea of what really to use whether a module or theme or both. Can you please tell me?

Comment: You can use any one of them. If you have created a custom module you can use it else in your custom theme you can also place files in layout and template folders.